# Flickering back-face visibility when 'flipping' a box using back-face visibility

Tags: css, safari, webkit, transform, css-transitions

I'm using a reasonably simple CSS transition to create a box that 'flips around' by transitioning two divs 180deg at the same time. When you're on the 'back' of the box, it should be slightly transparent so you can see the underside.

I've got this working fairly easily in all browers, except the latest Safari 7 and on iOS 7. On Safari 7, the animation flickers and the back card just 'pops' to the front at the end of the animation.

This seems to be a bug in the rendering of the animation on newer Safari. Is there a workaround to get this to behave better?

Check out gifs of the animation on [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnFJR.gif) and [Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4MCa.gif)

See a demo here http://cssdeck.com/labs/flippable-card

Comment: Until now I can only come up with a [hack involving 2 'back' cards for Safari 7](http://cssdeck.com/labs/166vjdxy). Hopefully I can do it without introducing extra elements. Your demo works fine on my iPhone running iOS 7 though.

Comment: Can not test on safari, but a similar bug happened time ago in Chrome. The solution in that case would have been to move the back 1px in z  .card__back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


.card--flipped .card__back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg)  translateZ(1px);
}

Comment: @vals, would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 17):

Can not test on safari, but a similar bug happened time ago in Chrome.

The solution in that case would have been to move the back 1px in z

```
.card__back { 
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px); 
    backface-visibility: hidden; 
} 

.card--flipped .card__back {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(1px); 
}
```

This happened in Chrome because while animating, the spatial order was calculated (I mean, the position of elements in 3d space), and it overrides other factors.

Once the animation is over, that calculation system  is no longer used.

As I said before; cann't test in Safari, so I can be sure that this is a solution.

Comment: Hello, that works fine in Safari, i have come through that bug a few time, and could only keep things a bit away to avoid it, where translate() was just the way to make thing work properly. +1 of course thks

Comment: something that may also help is, if you have your cards positioned (which you likely do), set the `z-index` on your "front" card to be higher than the "back"

Answer (score 3):

So I managed to replicate the behaviour in my current Safari and thought it was quite interesting.
Here's what I've come up with:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/usGCL

Basically the backside is already turned around through a `-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);` right from the start.

That way you don't have to rotate it back to 0deg.
Now instead of flipping front and back, You just flip the whole container by 180deg, leaving the backside appearing "normal" again. Also the z-index has to change in the process, which makes `backface-visibility: hidden;` redundant. I guess if modified a little you could use even less jQuery of course.

**EDIT**

Guess  Aperçu's answer is also pretty much what you were looking for.
Just for fun though: http://codepen.io/BenMann/pen/DmjHv

And I agree the backface-visibility is definitely causing the problem.

Comment: +1 for approaching this with rotating the container. I suggest a slight change though: applying a `.show-back` class to `#wrap` and toggling only it with jQuery. The rest of the styling can then be moved into the stylesheet using child/descendant selector e.g. `.show-back>.back {z-index: 2}`  Ah, old memories, just 5 years ago this needed Flash and a few dozen lines of ActionScript! :)

Comment: For sharing the love :]

Comment: Only that really helped (year 2020)! `transform: scaleX(-1) translateZ(-1px);` and removing `backface-visibility: hidden;` for the .back face. Even Chrome has that issue in delaying the actual rendering after faces flipper. Working now both in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the question, there are two things happening:

**1. The animation flickers:** this is due to the click delay in mobile browsers. Basically, a click event fires 300ms after physically tabbing the element. You'd want to listen for `touchstart` which fires immediately on tabbing, but doesn't fire at all on non-touch interfaces ([Fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) is a nice polyfill that removes this click delay in mobile browsers, but doesn't affect non-touch UIs.)

For the sake of this answer, I'm simply going to bind my listener to `touchstart` instead of `click` (therefore, the demo is to be viewed on a touch device):

```
$('.card').on("touchstart", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('card--flipped');
});
```

**2. The back card just 'pops' to the front at the end of the animation:** after some experimentation, it seems that this happens when `transform` and `backface-visibility` are both defined on the same element. To work around that, I've kept the `backface-visibily` on `.card__back`, but put the `transform: rotateY(180deg)` on `.card__front`.

Therefore, `.card__front` is going to be flipped initially, which means that `.card` has to be initially flipped as well to compensate for that.

We must also define `transform-style: preserve-3d` on `.card` in order for the `transform` to render `.card__front` and `.card__back` in 3D space (as opposed to being flattened).

```
/* Relevant CSS */

.card {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card__front {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.card__back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card--flipped {
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

**Mobile DEMO (to be viewed in mobile Safari or Chrome):** http://jsbin.com/aMAwezA/15/

**DEMO (for non-touch devices):** http://jsbin.com/aMAwezA/16/

**EDIT:**
After further testing, I found that `transform: rotateY(180deg)` on `.card__front` was causing some flickering in Chrome. Replacing it with `transform: scaleX(-1)` solved the issue. Updated the CSS and demo link above which should work on both mobile Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This looks very interesting. I'll see how this works in my project

Answer (score 1):

You need to add two transition time, one for the `-webkit-backface-visibility` and another for  `-webkit-transform`.

If you try to set the transition delay at 0secs, you will see the color change immediatly like you want to.

Try to modify your transition rule like

```
transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out, -webkit-backface-visibility 0s ease-in-out;
```

Or to override the 1sec transition only for the backface-visibility.

**EDIT**

Without using `-webkit-backface-visibility` which seems buggy, I think I've got something work playing with the `display` of the backcard.

See <kbd>[Demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/m2ioykqr)</kbd> (Tested on Safari 7 iOs 7.0.2 and Mavericks)

Comment: Are you able to post a demonstration with this working? I'm not sure if I understood your answer because I can't get it to work (make the Safari 7 animation look like Chrome)

Comment: Sorry, I was sure it was possible to separate transition timers using this syntax but I just discover browserstack and it seems not. Edited my answer

Comment: Just use `transition: all 1s ease-in-out` assuming he doesn't care about other properties animating